# How find this $a^2_{n}-2b^2_{n}=?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $\{a_{n}\},\{b_{n}\}$ such $a_{0}=b_{0}=1$
and 
$$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+2b_{n-1},b_{n}=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1},n=1,2,\cdots,n$$
show  that
$$a^2_{n}-2b^2_{n}=?$$

Comment: HINT: Subtract then replace the value of $a_{n-1}$ in the second equation

Comment: can you post ? Thank you

Comment: this HINT will help you to use this(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving). I'll post one once I've something better:)

Answer (score 1):

If you literally do what the question says, that is to remove $2b_n^2$ from $a_n^2$ directly, something interesting happens:

$$\begin{align}a_n^2 - 2b_n^2 &= (a_{n-1} + 2b_{n-1})^2 - 2(a_{n-1} + b_{n-1})^2\\
&= \left(a_{n-1}^2 + 4a_{n-1}b_{n-1} + 4b_{n-1}^2\right) \\
&-\left(2a_{n-1}^2 + 4a_{n-1}b_{n-1} + 2b_{n-1}^2\right)\\
&= -a_{n-1}^2 + 2b_{n-1}^2\\
&= -\left(a_{n-1}^2 - 2b_{n-1}^2\right)\end{align}$$

I imagine its easy to continue on from here.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$a_n^2 = a_{n-1}^2 + 4a_{n-1}b_{n-1} + 4b_{n-1}^2 $$
and 
$$b_n^2 = a_{n-1}^2 + 2a_{n-1}b_{n-1} + b_{n-1}^2 $$
hence 
$$ a_n^2 - 2b_n^2 = -a_{n-1}^2 + 2b_{n-1}^2 = -(a_{n-1}^2 - 2b_{n-1}^2) $$
Hence 
$$ a_n^2 - 2b_n^2 = (-1)^n (a_0 - 2b_0) = (-1)^{n+1}. $$